# PHP gearman workers equivalent in GO?

Tags: php, go, gearman

I'm working on one project which is processing data. Every 5 minutes cron executes go script which is doing all job. One part of job is taking a little more performance and more important, it's taking to much time so I would like to take this part of proccess and put in separate go script. This script would receive proccess_id and do that stuff while main job can continue and important, it would not wait that background go script finishes. It's not required that background job call me back when it's done (that info would be saved in db).

That kind of situation in PHP would be solved by gearman worker which you call, send data and you can contiue with your job while gearman is processing data by himself in background

Is there any similar in go lang which can also be called and not over http?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the go bindings for gearman. Check it out here:

https://github.com/mikespook/gearman-go

This is linked from the [downloads](http://gearman.org/download/) section of the main gearman site.